# Sublime Package Control Errno 13

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, package-control

Whenever I open up Sublime on my Window 7 machine I get an error about Package Control not having permissions to access a temp folder as it tries to update packages. [image: Errno 13]

I've tried resetting the permissions of the parent folder to no avail, and tried to create a new temp directory and still encountered the error. Even running the app as administrator doesn't seem to help.

Is there something else I'm missing here?

```
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3114 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/jlesc/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/jlesc/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/jlesc/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Material Theme", "SHS-At-Rule", "SHS-Bourbon-Neat", "SHS-Compass-Mixins", "SHS-Compass-Variables", "SHS-CSS-Properties", "SHS-CSS-Property-Values", "SHS-Sass-Functions", "Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.0998618
startup time: 0.119862
first paint time: 0.121862
first paint time: 0.121862
reloading plugin Default.auto_indent_tag
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.convert_syntax
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.profile
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.run_syntax_tests
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.show_scope_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.02-bz2
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBar
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarAPI
reloading plugin SideBarEnhancements.SideBarDefaultDisable
reloading plugin TrailingSpaces.trailing_spaces
plugins loaded
Package Control: Installing 1 missing package
reloading settings Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
error: Package Control

An error occurred creating the package file Material Theme.sublime-package in c:\users\jlesc\appdata\local\tmp\tmp5bsz0p.

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\users\\jlesc\\appdata\\local\\tmp\\tmp5bsz0p\\Material Theme.sublime-package'
```

Comment: Please turn on debug mode in the Package Control User settings, then completely restart Sublime and post the contents of the console (Ctrl-`) in your question.

Comment: @MattDMo good call.

Comment: @Picard102 I am getting this too.   Can you please post how you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

change the security settings and give yourself full permissions to modify and write to the sublime text folder both in your app data and your program files. Worked for me